# How can I parse string which is date?

Tags: c++

I have a string which is date. Is there a function from standart library which can parse it in any numeric format(e.g timestamp or julian day)

For example

```
 std::string str("01/01/2017");//Local format date
 UINT64 timestamp = function(str);
```

I don't want to pass format date in a function. I want to know only that a string represented in local format.

Comment: _“I don't want to pass format date in a function.”_ So the function should _guess_ whether the format is MM/DD/YYYY, or DD/MM/YYYY? I definitely wouldn’t rely on that.

Comment: `_variant_t` does it

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the local date format you can try [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) (available since C++11)

> When used in an expression in >> get_time(tmb, fmt), parses the character input as a date/time value according to format string fmt according to the std::time_get facet of the locale currently imbued in the input stream in.

or the POSIX C function [`strptime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) with `"x"` as format.

> |   x |   parses the locale's standard date representation |  all |
> -- cppreference.com

Both return calendar time `struct tm` that you can convert it to timestamp using either `localtime` or `gmtime` if you want.

Note that you have to set the C and C++ locale of your application before, in order to be able to use your OS regional settings and not the classic C locale. See `locale` and `std::locale`. And it's good to set both so that they are in sync and not get bad surprises.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
std::locale::global(std::locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)));
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use format. I want to use like `_variant_t`. But I need cross platform solution

Comment: There is a time facet in the locale, I have to look at how to get the format from it

Comment: `strftime` prints into string, not parses it.

Comment: You're right. The parsing function is strptime and is available only POSIX conform platforms like Linux.